# Problem with convex function

Tags: functions, convex-analysis

In Papadimitriou book I found a problem. If I know that function $f$ is a convex function, and I have values $x_2,...,x_n$, is function $g(x_1) = f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ also a convex function?
I know definition of convex function, but I don't know how to use it, when I have function of many arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look when $n=2$. We have that the function $f(x,y)$ is convex, that is
$$f(\lambda x +(1-\lambda) x', \lambda y +(1-\lambda) y')\le \lambda f(x,y)+
(1-\lambda)f(x',y')$$
for any $(x,y), (x',y')$ and $\lambda\in(0,1)$.

If $y=y_0$ is fixed, then we get for $g(x)=f(x,y_0)$
$$g(\lambda x +(1-\lambda) x')=f(\lambda x +(1-\lambda) x', y_0)=
f(\lambda x +(1-\lambda) x', \lambda y_0 +(1-\lambda) y_0)$$
$$\le \lambda f(x,y_0)+
(1-\lambda)f(x',y_0)=\lambda g(x)+(1-\lambda)g(x')$$
for any $x, x'$ and $\lambda\in(0,1)$.